# variable or field (function) declared void

Tags: c++, matrix, compiler-errors

I am writing some basic matrix functions and am getting an error that I cannot figure out how to diagnose.

I have a function in my .h file:

```
void matrixMultiplication (int arr1[][100], int arr2[][100], int a1row, int a2col, int targetArr[][100]);
```

In my .cpp file I have:

```
void matrixMultiplication (matrix1, matrix2, rowOfMatrix1, columnOfMatrix2, finalMatrix);
```

which is defined as

```
void matrixMultiplication (int arr1[][100], int arr2[][100], int a1row, int a2col, int targetArr[][100]) {
    for (int a = 0; a < a1row; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < a2col; b++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < a2col; c++) {
                targetArr[a][b] += arr1[a][c]*arr2[c][b];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is declared here:

```
//designates the sizes of both matrices
int rowOfMatrix1 = 0;
int columnOfMatrix1 = 0;
    // size of matrix 1 = rowOfMatrix1 x columnOfMatrix1
int rowOfMatrix2 = 0;
int columnOfMatrix2= 0;
    // size of matrix 2 = rowOfMatrix2 x columnOfMatrix2

//arrays that hold the values of the integers in the matrices
int matrix1 [100][100];
int matrix2 [100][100];
int finalMatrix [100][100];
```

However, when I run the program, I get the following error:

```
In function 'int main()' [Error] variable or field 'matrixMultiplication' declared void
```

I see that this question has been asked before but the answer had to do with strings, which have nothing to do with my program, and I cannot figure out how to extend that answer to this case.

Comment: Why do you specify a return type when you *call* the function?

Comment: On an unrelated note, I hope you initialize `finalMatrix` somewhere before the call, or you will have *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler thinks that you're declaring a variable named `matrixMultiplication`, which is initialised with the parameters you gave and whose type is `void`.
You can't create a variable of type `void`.

You shouldn't specify the return type when you call a function, so remove the `void`:

```
matrixMultiplication (matrix1, matrix2, rowOfMatrix1, columnOfMatrix2, finalMatrix);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try removing `void` from below line and re-compile. It should fix the problem.

```
void matrixMultiplication (matrix1, matrix2, rowOfMatrix1, columnOfMatrix2, finalMatrix);
```

While calling function, return type should not be given. That's why compiler is complaining.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, You are right. I meant removing void and not function call itself :(